# Can you split one typeform in two pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm implementing a typeform and I want to customize it a bit. I want the users to submit their emailadress on the homepage and complete the other questions on another detail page. I'm passing the emailadress via the url right now, but I can't send it to the TypeForm iframe. Anyone who has done this before?

```
<form class="form-inline" action="join.html" method="GET">
  <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="angel.investor@example.com" name="email">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default reverse" value="Join now!"></input>
</form>
```

My url is something like this: `somethinglikethis.com/join.html?email=john.doe@something.com`

And jQuery on join.html:

```
$("div.typeform-widget div.input input[type='text']").val(window.location.search);
    $('iframe').css('display', 'none');
```

I tried a lot of other things as well, but I can't make it work...

Comment: why dont you save the email id in a variable and then access it from within the iframe?

Comment: Tried it before, but it seems like the iframe blocks any javascript input...

Comment: No it wont, But its not straight forward to access it. I will post my answer, Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So the idea is, Set the email in the JavaScript variable, And then access the variable from within the iframe and set it to an hidden field of the iframe.

To save the variable into JavaScript global scope do this.

```
$('form[action="join.html"]').on('submit',function(){
   window.ClientEmailId = $('#exampleInputEmail2').val(); 
//save the email id into a variable in the window scope (global scope)      
});
```

Then inside your iframe you can extract the value like below,

```
var emailId = parent.window.ClientEmailId;
// you can save to any hidden input and use this value further
```

You need to start from the iframe parent, that would be the main window and then access the value from there.

**NOTE:** This will work if both iframe and your main page are under the same domain.

let me know if this helps